# Objective-C static const variables

Tags: objective-c, static, initialization, constants

I am trying to create a class with static const variables that can be used from outside the class, but I cannot figure out how to initialize this variable.

Example Code:

```
@interface ExampleClass
{
 static const int CONST_VAR;
}

- (id) init;

@end
@implementation ExampleClass

- (id) init {
 CONST_VAR = 1;
}

@end
```

I want to be able to reference the static constant variable like this:

```
ExampleClass.CONST_VAR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a value to this static variable by doing the following:

```
-(id)init{
    ExampleClass.CONST_VAR = 1;
}
```

Because this is a static variable or "class variable", you must use the class name in any case regardless of where you are this includes from inside the same class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found my problem, the static variables, should have been in the @implementation